# Heroku on Ubuntu 10.04 (RVM with 1.9.2)

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails

so I'm trying to install heroku and when I run it I get the following message:

```
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/restclient.rb:9:in `rescue in <top (required)>': no such file to load -- net/https. Try running apt-get install libopenssl-ruby (LoadError)
    from /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/restclient.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/heroku-1.9.14/lib/heroku/client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/heroku-1.9.14/lib/heroku.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/gems/heroku-1.9.14/bin/heroku:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@seniorproject/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I've installed the suggested library but it still doesn't work. Is this something I'm going to have to recompile ruby for? If so, what packages should I install beforehand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I gave up on getting 1.9.2 running with Rails 3 & Heroku for the time being. However [OSDIR mailing list mentions below instructions](http://osdir.com/ml/RubyonRailsTalk/2010-08/msg02654.html)

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
$ rvm package install openssl
$ rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: What version of Ruby is working for you?

Comment: @Reactor I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 p249 ( the one which came with Ubuntu) + Rails 3. Although do note I'm just learning Rails.

Comment: Same here, actually. Installing the openssl-dev package fixed it for me. Of course, the next requirement for heroku is libreadline5-dev. We'll see if I've got them all after this.

Comment: This worked. I ran the calls described here, and installed libreadline5-dev and it all worked.

Comment: @Reactor5 Good to hear. Marking this question as favourite for future reference for me!

Answer (score 1):

the "package" call doesn't exist (maybe that's the old name)

You can do it more directly with:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Answer (score 0):

I completed the Installation process with `rvm`, `ruby 1.9.2` and `sqlite3`. You gave up in the last step.

This worked for me after 2 days of wrestling with heroku:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/readline
```

and then build the extension

```
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```